# Why does a debugging point affect DPI of a figure in matplotlib?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, matplotlib

Here is a very simple matplotlib snippet:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figure = plt.figure(figsize=[3.19907407, 1.79861111], dpi=432.0)

print('1: size', plt.gcf().get_size_inches(), 'dpi', plt.gcf().get_dpi())
plt.gcf().set_size_inches([1.799131693198264, 1.8])
print('2: size', plt.gcf().get_size_inches(), 'dpi', plt.gcf().get_dpi())

plt.show()
```

If I run it normally, or in debug mode, the output is as expected:

```
1: size [3.19675926 1.7962963 ] dpi 432.0
2: size [1.79861111 1.79861111] dpi 432.0
```

If I run it with a breakpoint, as on the screenshot, then go over the next lines step by step...

[image]

... the output is

```
1: size [3.19675926 1.7962963 ] dpi 864.0
2: size [1.79861111 1.79861111] dpi 864.0
```

I have also seen the situation (that I cannot reproduce with a small snippet), where running `set_size_inches` (without doing anything else) would double DPI, so the equivalent output would be

```
1: size [3.19675926 1.7962963 ] dpi 432.0
2: size [1.79861111 1.79861111] dpi 864.0
```

Would anyone know why this doubling of DPI is happening and how to avoid it?

Comment: I have no idea what's going on here, but do you see the same doubling if you use `figure` instead of `plt.gcf()`?

Comment: @Stef : just checked, the doubling is exactly as it was with `gcf`

Comment: then I don't know, sorry

Comment: Because you are plotting on a display with a dpiRatio of 2.  In general you will be far better off if you do not think about dpi until you display the figure.

Comment: @JodyKlymak it would be nice not to have to think about it, but I sometimes need to debug my code , thus the question :) I am using the same display for all three runs, why would the result be different?

Comment: Because when the dpi ratio is consulted depends on when you do a draw to screen.  I don’t personally think this should affect the canonical figure dpi, and I think that with latest MPL it does not, but..  It would also be helpful to know what backend you are using.

Comment: @JodyKlymak: "Backend MacOSX is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on." - that's my backend. My suspicion is that dpi should not be affected by the absence/presence of the debugging points, that it's probably a matplotlib bug (they have known dpi bugs that were not fixed yet.)